# Use Latest Mono (4.9) on Ubuntu instead of 3.2.8

Tags: software-installation, apache2, mono, monodevelop

I have a Ubuntu VPS running Mono v3.2.8. I'm trying to upgrade it to the latest mono v4.9 using these instructions.
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/ci-packages/

I installed the latest snapshot. Then what?

v3.2.8 is still installed and there might be conflicts between both versions. Websites still use v3.2.8. I tried uninstalling it but apparently I haven't fully succeeded as websites are still running with it.

If I try to switch to the latest version using ". mono-snapshot mono", it simply adds "[mono-2017.01.22+16.25.00]" at the beginning of the command line. What is that?

The website configuration files in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ contain this. Does this need to be changed?

```
<IfModule mod_mono.c>
  MonoServerPath mydomain.com "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
  MonoApplications mydomain.com "/:/var/www/mydomain"
</IfModule>
```

So... what are the next steps to get v4.9 up and running?

Edit:
I just found out it gets installed in
/opt/mono-2017.01.23+22.17.42/
and configuration file is in this folder
/usr/share/mono-snapshot/packages.d/mono
Now... how do I configure my server to use that version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking of it, installing a development snapshot might not be the best idea on a production server; and that's why such instructions aren't clear.

If I add the right PPA, it might update to the latest version without needing to change anything.

Indeed, I was following the wrong instructions. This gives me the right PPA that updates MONO to the latest version. I uninstalled the snapshots.
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives

Now I have MONO v4.6.2 installed :)